# How can I name a sqlite column "primary" with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to create this table in Rails:

```
create_table :artist_names do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.boolean :primary, :default => true
  t.integer :artist_id

  t.datetime :deleted_at
  t.timestamps
end
```

However, my queries against it fail:

```
[Dev]> ArtistName.all(:conditions => ['artist_names.primary = ?', true])  ArtistName Load (0.0ms)
SQLite3::SQLException: near "primary": syntax error: SELECT * FROM "artist_names" WHERE (artist_names.primary = 't') AND ("artist_names"."deleted_at" IS NULL)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "primary": syntax error: SELECT * FROM "artist_names" WHERE (artist_names.primary = 't') AND ("artist_names"."deleted_at" IS NULL)
```

My queries work when I change the column's name to something else, but the name "primary" makes the most sense to me.

How can I make this work while keeping the column name "primary"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User back-ticks around primary word.

```
ArtistName.all(:conditions => ['`primary` = ?', true]) ...
```

Comment: This is correct, but the real answer is "rename the column"; Rails doesn't know about the backtick rule, and so you can't depend on it when using ActiveRecord